# Shopware custom theme

Tags: php, shopware6

I want to make a custom shopware theme, created one by using the documentation. Emptied out my `theme.json`. Expectation is theme without anything, no markup, no content nothing. I come from WooCommerce, so an empty theme means an empty frontend.

When i visit the frontend of my shopware theme i see this:

[image]

Why is there any content? I haven't done any templating yet.

Also, if i view my theme settings:

[image]

Why is my theme derived from 'Shopware default theme' ??? And why are there theme settings present? My theme is *empty*.

As i come from WooCommerce, this is really confusing, even after reading the docs.

I'd love someone to clarify this.

My theme.json:

```
{
    "name": "Rowan",
    "author": "RvZ",
    "views": [],
    "style": [],
    "script": [],
    "asset": []
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you seriously want a completely blank slate, then you could empty the `views` property in your `theme.json` **except** for your own theme alias.

```json
{
  "name": "Rowan",
  "author": "...",
  "views": [
     "@Rowan"
  ],
  "style": [
  ],
  "script": [
  ],
  "asset": [
  ],
  "configInheritance": [
  ]
}
```

Then based from your theme's root directory create an empty `src/Resources/views/storefront/base.html.twig`.

You might then have to clear the cache so the changes take effect.

This will leave you with basically nothing. Keep in mind you will have to implement many templates of the default storefront templates yourself at that point, from ground up no less. You'd need to recreate the original directory structure as well as the controllers will require to render different templates in specific directories.

As for the theme configuration there are just some basic fields that will always be shown within the administration. I don't know of a way to remove these even if your theme inherits nothing from the default storefront.

Comment: That worked, awesome! I read more of the documentation, i came to the conclusion that changing templates is something only plugins should do? Is that right? Shouldnt a theme also change how a template looks?

Comment: In addition to altering the look and feel of the storefront, it's perfectly fine for a theme to extend, replace or overwrite templates/blocks with custom markup. If you don't need to introduce changes to the business logic, a theme offers a more slim-line solution to do that. A plugin may do all that as well, but in addition a plugin may have touchpoints with the api and include custom business logic.